# How do I get the sys time in nasm x64 but, in milliseconds?

Tags: linux, assembly, time, x86-64, nasm

So I am still kind of a beginner in NASM x64. I am writing a rock paper scissors program and I decided that instead of getting a random number I should just get the last digit of milliseconds. I already know how to get the time in seconds:

```
section .text:
    global _start
_start:
    mov rax, 201
    xor rdx, rdx      ; if rdx is empty, the time value will go to rax
    syscall
    ; exit
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

I've tested it out and it works. How can I do the exact same thing, but rax will hold the value in milliseconds? (I am not saying multiply by 1000, I want the real value)

I have looked for a really long time: went through the syscall table, searched it up, look at a university's course plan. I even asked an AI. So I'm at my last resort asking you guys. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Or if you just want some randomness from the low few bits of a time, use `rdtsc` instead of a system call.  The high bits are just as non-random as a wall-clock time, but it doesn't tick synchronously with execution so the low few bits shouldn't be correlated across runs if there's any manual / external human-driven delay.  Or run it once to seed a PRNG, if `rdrand` isn't available. [Random number generation in assembly NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53580871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `gettimeofday` system call which gives you microseconds, or `clock_gettime` that gives you nanoseconds.  They are a little more work to call, since they return the time in a buffer rather than in a register, but you can allocate a temporary buffer on the stack.  If you specifically care about getting milliseconds, then divide by 1000 or 1000000 accordingly.

If you're going to go to the trouble to make a system call, though, why not do it right and call [`getrandom(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) for some more truly random bytes?

Untested example of `getrandom`:

```
    sub rsp, 16    ; make some stack space, maintain alignment
    mov rdi, rsp   ; point rdi at our stack buffer
    mov esi, 1     ; read one byte
    xor edx, edx   ; no flags needed
    mov eax, 318   ; see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/constants/syscalls.md#x86_64-64_bit
    syscall
    ; check for errors here; left as an exercise
    movzx eax, byte [rsp]  ; load the byte from stack into eax, zero the high bits
    add rsp, 16    ; clean up the stack
```

Comment: how do i call the getrandom(2)??

Comment: @IsmellBeans: I added an example.

Comment: Syscall numbers are available locally, in `asm/unistd_64.h`.  Use `locate unistd_64.h` to find it, if your system doesn't put it at `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`

Comment: so i had to fix up a little bit of things in your answer (edx -> rdx, esi -> rsi and eax -> rax). It compiles. I haven't tested if it works but i need to know one more thing, how do i reset a variable

Comment: @IsmellBeans: They are actually correct as is.  [Writes to 32-bit registers zero the upper half](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6), so `mov esi, 1` does the same as `mov rsi, 1` and is one byte shorter.   This is a standard micro-optimization. I don't know what you mean by "reset a variable", though.  Do you mean set it to zero?

Comment: if i set a variable from the .bss section, then, i want to clear that variable and rewrite a different value. Is that possible and how?

Comment: @IsmellBeans: Just write the new value, with a `mov` to memory or whatever else makes sense.  RAM isn't EEPROM, you don't have to do a separate "clear" step in between.