# Randomizing Numbers in Assembly with MASM32

Tags: windows, assembly, random, masm, masm32

How can I randomize a number using Assembly with Masm32? What can I use to create a random numbers generator?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want to implement your own pseudo-random function or do you just want to know how to call `rand()` from asm ?

Comment: I want to know how to call rand() from asm

Comment: I used this solution and it works!

 invoke  GetTickCount
 invoke  nseed, eax
 invoke  nrandom, 10
 invoke  dwtoa, eax, offset lpszNumber
 invoke  StdOut, offset lpszNumber

Comment: `crc32 %eax` would probably be the simplest PRNG available on SSE4.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Get random numbers with MASM32

The [MASM32 SDK](http://www.masm32.com/) comes with some examples which implement random generators. It isn't the worst idea to use them for own purposes. The following examples are just examples and lack - among others - in an error handling. The examples generate and produce 30 random numbers in the range [0..11].

A [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) with a=134775813 and b=c (like Delphi) is in *\masm32\examples\exampl03\lcd\lcd.asm*.

```
.686
.MODEL flat, STDCALL

INCLUDE kernel32.inc        ; GetStdHandle, WriteFile, ExitProcess
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib

INCLUDE user32.inc          ; wsprintf
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

NumberOfNumbers = 30        ; Number of random numbers to be generated and shown
RangeOfNumbers = 12         ; Range of the random numbers (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

.DATA
    RandSeed    dd  ?

.CODE
PseudoRandom PROC                       ; Deliver EAX: Range (0..EAX-1)
      push  edx                         ; Preserve EDX
      imul  edx,RandSeed,08088405H      ; EDX = RandSeed * 0x08088405 (decimal 134775813)
      inc   edx
      mov   RandSeed, edx               ; New RandSeed
      mul   edx                         ; EDX:EAX = EAX * EDX
      mov   eax, edx                    ; Return the EDX from the multiplication
      pop   edx                         ; Restore EDX
      ret
ret
PseudoRandom ENDP                       ; Return EAX: Random number in range

main PROC
    rdtsc
    mov RandSeed, eax                   ; Initialize random generator

    mov ecx, NumberOfNumbers            ; Loop counter - show ECX random numbers
    LL1:
    push ecx                            ; Preserve loop counter

    mov eax, RangeOfNumbers             ; Range (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)
    call PseudoRandom

    call write_number                   ; printf ("%u ", EAX)

    pop ecx                             ; Restore loop counter
    loop LL1

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

write_number PROC STDCALL USES ebx      ; printf ("%u ", EAX)
LOCAL numstring[12]:BYTE, NumberOfBytesWritten:DWORD
.CONST
    fmt db "%u ",0
.CODE
    invoke wsprintf, ADDR numstring, ADDR fmt, eax
    mov ebx, eax                        ; Preserve result - count of written bytes
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11            ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov edx, eax                        ; EAX will be used by the following INVOKE
    invoke WriteFile, edx, ADDR numstring, ebx, ADDR NumberOfBytesWritten, 0
    ret
write_number ENDP

END main
```

A [XORshifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) can be found in *\masm32\examples\exampl04\pascal\pascal.asm*.

```
.686
.MODEL flat, STDCALL

INCLUDE kernel32.inc        ; GetStdHandle, WriteFile, ExitProcess
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib

INCLUDE user32.inc          ; wsprintf
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

NumberOfNumbers = 30        ; Number of random numbers to be generated and shown
RangeOfNumbers = 12         ; Range of the random numbers (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

.CODE
Rnd3Bit Proc        ; This procedure generates up to 20 random bits (EAX=0..20).
.DATA
    RndInit dd 0A2F59C2Eh
.CODE
    mov edx,RndInit
rl: rol edx, 1
    jnc rs
    xor edx, 0Ah
rs: dec eax
    jne rl
    mov eax, edx
    rcr edx, 1
    mov RndInit, edx
ret
Rnd3Bit EndP

main PROC
    rdtsc                           ; Any number for the first seed
    test eax, eax                   ; EAX == 0?
    setz dl                         ; DL=1 if EAX==0, DL=0 if EAX>0
    or eax, edx                     ; Not 0 under any circumstances
    mov RndInit, eax                ; Reinitialize random generator

    mov ecx, NumberOfNumbers        ; Loop counter - show ECX random numbers
    LL1:
    push ecx                        ; Preserve loop counter

    mov eax, 20                     ; Amount of bits
    call Rnd3Bit
    and eax, 11111111111111111111b  ; 20 bits set = 1048575

    mov ecx, RangeOfNumbers         ; Range (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)
    xor edx, edx                    ; Needed for DIV
    div ecx                         ; EDX:EAX/ECX -> EAX remainder EDX
    mov eax, edx                    ; Get the remainder

    call write_number               ; printf ("%u ", EAX)
    pop ecx                         ; Restore loop counter
    loop LL1

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

write_number PROC STDCALL USES ebx  ; printf ("%u ", EAX)
LOCAL numstring[12]:BYTE, NumberOfBytesWritten:DWORD
.CONST
    fmt db "%u ",0
.CODE
    invoke wsprintf, ADDR numstring, ADDR fmt, eax
    mov ebx, eax                    ; Preserve count of written bytes
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11        ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov edx, eax                    ; EAX will be used by the following INVOKE
    invoke WriteFile, edx, ADDR numstring, ebx, ADDR NumberOfBytesWritten, 0
    ret
write_number ENDP

END main
```

The [Park-Miller-Algorithm](https://books.google.de/books?id=vEN-ckcdtCwC&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q&f=false) is used in *\masm32\examples\exampl05\rpg\rpg.asm*

```
.686
.MODEL flat, STDCALL

INCLUDE kernel32.inc        ; GetStdHandle, WriteFile, ExitProcess
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib

INCLUDE user32.inc          ; wsprintf
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

NumberOfNumbers = 30        ; Number of random numbers to be generated and shown
RangeOfNumbers = 12         ; Range of the random numbers (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

.DATA
rseed dd 0
range dd 0

.CODE

nrandom PROC
; ------------------
; NaN's nrandom algo (Park Miller random algorithm)
; ------------------
  lpstart:
    mov eax, rseed
    test eax, 80000000h
    jz  @F
    add eax, 7FFFFFFFh
  @@:
    xor edx, edx
    mov ecx, 127773
    div ecx
    mov ecx, eax
    mov eax, 16807
    mul edx
    mov edx, ecx
    mov ecx, eax
    mov eax, 2836
    mul edx
    sub ecx, eax
    xor edx, edx
    mov eax, ecx
    mov rseed, ecx
    div range

    mov eax, edx                        ; Write DWORD result to return register
    add rseed, 1                        ; New value to rseed

    ret
nrandom ENDP

main PROC
    rdtsc
    mov rseed, eax                      ; Reinitialize random generator

    mov ecx, NumberOfNumbers            ; Loop counter - show ECX random numbers

    LL1:
    push ecx                            ; Preserve loop counter

    mov range, RangeOfNumbers           ; Range (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)
    call nrandom

    call write_number                   ; printf ("%u ", EAX)

    pop ecx                             ; Restore loop counter
    loop LL1

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

write_number PROC STDCALL USES ebx      ; printf ("%u ", EAX)
LOCAL numstring[12]:BYTE, NumberOfBytesWritten:DWORD
.CONST
    fmt db "%u ",0
.CODE
    invoke wsprintf, ADDR numstring, ADDR fmt, eax
    mov ebx, eax                        ; Preserve count of written bytes
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11            ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov edx, eax                        ; EAX will be used by the following INVOKE
    invoke WriteFile, edx, ADDR numstring, ebx, ADDR NumberOfBytesWritten, 0
    ret
write_number ENDP

END main
```

*\masm32\examples\exampl07\shuflarr\sa.asm* uses the MASM32 built in `nrandom`. The source code  is located in *\masm32\m32lib\nrand.asm*. It's the same Park-Miller-Algorithm as above.

```
.686
.MODEL flat, STDCALL
OPTION casemap:none

INCLUDE kernel32.inc        ; GetStdHandle, WriteFile, ExitProcess
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib

INCLUDE user32.inc          ; wsprintf
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

INCLUDE masm32.inc          ; nseed, nrandom
INCLUDELIB masm32.lib

NumberOfNumbers = 30        ; Number of random numbers to be generated and shown
RangeOfNumbers = 12         ; Range of the random numbers (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

.CODE
main PROC
    rdtsc
    invoke nseed, eax                   ; Initialize nrandom_seed

    mov ecx, NumberOfNumbers            ; Loop counter - show ECX random numbers
    LL1:
    push ecx                            ; Preserve loop counter

    invoke nrandom, RangeOfNumbers      ; Range (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

    call write_number                   ; printf ("%u ", EAX)

    pop ecx                             ; Restore loop counter
    loop LL1

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

write_number PROC STDCALL USES ebx      ; printf ("%u ", EAX)
LOCAL numstring[12]:BYTE, NumberOfBytesWritten:DWORD
.CONST
    fmt db "%u ",0
.CODE
    invoke wsprintf, ADDR numstring, ADDR fmt, eax
    mov ebx, eax                        ; Preserve result - count of written bytes
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11            ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov edx, eax                        ; EAX will be used by the following INVOKE
    invoke WriteFile, edx, ADDR numstring, ebx, ADDR NumberOfBytesWritten, 0
    ret
write_number ENDP

END main
```

There are a lot of `.lib` files to acces the Windows system. Microsoft suggests to use `CryptGenRandom`:

```
.686
.MODEL flat, STDCALL
OPTION casemap:none

INCLUDE kernel32.inc        ; GetStdHandle, WriteFile, ExitProcess
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib

INCLUDE user32.inc          ; wsprintf
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

INCLUDE advapi32.inc        ; CryptAcquireContext, CryptGenRandom, CryptReleaseContext
INCLUDELIB advapi32.lib

NumberOfNumbers = 30        ; Number of random numbers to be generated and shown
RangeOfNumbers = 12         ; Range of the random numbers (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

.DATA
    random_bytes dd 30 DUP (?)
    hProvider dd ?

.CODE
main PROC
    ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa379886.aspx
    CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT = 0F0000000h
    PROV_RSA_FULL = 1
    invoke CryptAcquireContext, ADDR hProvider, 0, 0, PROV_RSA_FULL,CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT

    ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa379942.aspx
    invoke CryptGenRandom, hProvider, 30*4, ADDR random_bytes       ; Generate 30 random DWORD (30*4)

    ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa380268.aspx
    invoke CryptReleaseContext, hProvider, 0

    lea esi, random_bytes
    mov ecx, NumberOfNumbers            ; Loop counter - show ECX random numbers
    @@:
    push ecx                            ; Preserve loop counter

    lodsd                               ; [ESI] -> EAX, ADD ESI, 4

    ; Adjust EAX to the range
    mov ecx, RangeOfNumbers             ; Range (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)
    xor edx, edx                        ; Needed for DIV
    div ecx                             ; EDX:EAX/ECX -> EAX remainder EDX
    mov eax, edx                        ; Get the remainder

    call write_number                   ; printf ("%u ", EAX)

    pop ecx                             ; Restore loop counter
    loop @B                             ; Loop the next @@ above

    invoke ExitProcess, 0               ; Exit (0) = return 0
main ENDP

write_number PROC STDCALL USES ebx      ; printf ("%u ", EAX)
LOCAL numstring[12]:BYTE, NumberOfBytesWritten:DWORD
.CONST
    fmt db "%u ",0
.CODE
    invoke wsprintf, ADDR numstring, ADDR fmt, eax
    mov ebx, eax                        ; Preserve result - count of written bytes
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11            ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov edx, eax                        ; EAX will be used by the following INVOKE
    invoke WriteFile, edx, ADDR numstring, ebx, ADDR NumberOfBytesWritten, 0
    ret
write_number ENDP

END main
```

I found an undocumented function `Dns_GetRandomXid` in `dnsapi.lib`. It uses `CryptGenRandom` and sometimes the C function `rand()` and seems to be thread safe.

```
.686
.MODEL flat, STDCALL
OPTION casemap:none

INCLUDE kernel32.inc        ; GetStdHandle, WriteFile, ExitProcess
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib

INCLUDE user32.inc          ; wsprintf
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

INCLUDE dnsapi.inc          ; Dns_GetRandomXid
INCLUDELIB dnsapi.lib

NumberOfNumbers = 30        ; Number of random numbers to be generated and shown
RangeOfNumbers = 12         ; Range of the random numbers (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

.CODE
main PROC
    mov ecx, NumberOfNumbers            ; Loop counter - show ECX random numbers
    LL1:
    push ecx                            ; Preserve loop counter

    invoke Dns_GetRandomXid, 0          ; Argument not used -> AX = random WORD

    mov ecx, RangeOfNumbers             ; Range (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)
    xor edx, edx                        ; Needed for DIV
    div ecx                             ; EDX:EAX/ECX -> EAX remainder EDX
    mov eax, edx                        ; Get the remainder

    call write_number                   ; printf ("%u ", EAX)

    pop ecx                             ; Restore loop counter
    loop LL1

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

write_number PROC STDCALL USES ebx      ; printf ("%u ", EAX)
LOCAL numstring[12]:BYTE, NumberOfBytesWritten:DWORD
.CONST
    fmt db "%u ",0
.CODE
    invoke wsprintf, ADDR numstring, ADDR fmt, eax
    mov ebx, eax                        ; Preserve result - count of written bytes
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11            ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov edx, eax                        ; EAX will be used by the following INVOKE
    invoke WriteFile, edx, ADDR numstring, ebx, ADDR NumberOfBytesWritten, 0
    ret
write_number ENDP

END main
```

Another undocumented function is `CDGenerateRandomBits` in `cryptdll.lib`.

```
.686
.MODEL flat, STDCALL
OPTION casemap:none

INCLUDE kernel32.inc        ; GetStdHandle, WriteFile, ExitProcess
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib

INCLUDE user32.inc          ; wsprintf
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

INCLUDE cryptdll.inc        ; CDGenerateRandomBits
INCLUDELIB cryptdll.lib

NumberOfNumbers = 30        ; Number of random numbers to be generated and shown
RangeOfNumbers = 12         ; Range of the random numbers (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

.DATA
    random_bytes dd 30 DUP (?)

.CODE
main PROC
    invoke CDGenerateRandomBits, Addr random_bytes, (NumberOfNumbers*4)     ; Generate 120 random bytes (30 DWORD à 4 BYTE)

    lea esi, random_bytes
    mov ecx, 30                         ; Show 30 random numbers
    LL1:
    push ecx                            ; Preserve loop counter

    lodsd                               ; [ESI] -> EAX; ESI += 4

    ; Adjust EAX to range
    mov ecx, RangeOfNumbers             ; Range (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)
    xor edx, edx                        ; Needed for DIV
    div ecx                             ; EDX:EAX/ECX -> EAX remainder EDX
    mov eax, edx                        ; Get the remainder

    call write_number                   ; printf ("%u ", EAX)

    pop ecx                             ; Restore loop counter
    loop LL1

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

write_number PROC STDCALL USES ebx      ; printf ("%u ", EAX)
LOCAL numstring[12]:BYTE, NumberOfBytesWritten:DWORD
.CONST
    fmt db "%u ",0
.CODE
    invoke wsprintf, ADDR numstring, ADDR fmt, eax
    mov ebx, eax                        ; Preserve result - count of written bytes
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11            ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov edx, eax                        ; EAX will be used by the follwing INVOKE
    invoke WriteFile, edx, ADDR numstring, ebx, ADDR NumberOfBytesWritten, 0
    ret
write_number ENDP

END main
```

The good old `rand()` from the C library should not be missing.

```
.686
.MODEL flat, C

INCLUDE msvcrt.inc          ; crt_time, crt_srand, crt_rand, crt_printf,crt_exit
INCLUDELIB msvcrt.lib

NumberOfNumbers = 30        ; Number of random numbers to be generated and shown
RangeOfNumbers = 12         ; Range of the random numbers (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

.DATA
    fmt db "%u ", 0

.CODE
main PROC
    sub esp, 8                          ; Reserve place for the C arguments

    ;  srand( time (NULL) )
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], 0
    call crt_time                       ; EAX = time(0)
    mov [esp], eax
    call crt_srand                      ; srand (EAX)

    mov ebx, NumberOfNumbers            ; Loop counter - show ECX random numbers
    LL1:

    call crt_rand                       ; EAX = rand()

    ; Adjust EAX to the range
    mov ecx, RangeOfNumbers             ; Range (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)
    xor edx, edx                        ; Needed for DIV
    div ecx                             ; EDX:EAX/ECX -> EAX remainder EDX
    mov eax, edx                        ; Get the remainder

    ; printf ("%d\n", EAX )
    mov [esp], OFFSET fmt
    mov [esp+4], eax
    call crt_printf                     ; printf (fmt,eax)

    dec ebx
    jne LL1

    ; exit (0) = return 0
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], 0
    call crt_exit                       ; exit (0) = return 0
main ENDP

END main
```

On a modern processor (at least [Ivy Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge_(microarchitecture)) - since 2012) there is implemented the instruction [`RDRAND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand). It meets the [NIST SP 800-90A standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_SP_800-90A). The MASM assembler in the MASM32 SDK cannot assemble this instruction. A workaround is to insert instruction as a series of hexadecimal bytes into the code. MASM will store it as given and the processor will execute it as desired.

```
.686
.MODEL flat, STDCALL

INCLUDE kernel32.inc        ; GetStdHandle, WriteFile, ExitProcess
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib

INCLUDE user32.inc          ; wsprintf
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

NumberOfNumbers = 30        ; Number of random numbers to be generated and shown
RangeOfNumbers = 12         ; Range of the random numbers (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

.CONST
    err_text db "ERR: RDRAND not supported.",10,0

.CODE
main PROC
    mov eax, 01h                        ; Check for availability (EAX=1) -> ECX.30
    cpuid
    bt ecx, 30                          ; CPUID.01H:ECX.RDRAND[bit 30] = 1 ?
    jnc err_exit                        ; No (RDRAND not supported) -> err_exit

    mov ecx, NumberOfNumbers            ; Loop counter - generate and show ECX random numbers
    LL1:
    push ecx                            ; Preserve loop counter

    @@:
    db 0Fh, 0C7h, 0F0h                  ; rdrand eax
    jnc @B                              ; Invalid number - try again

    ; Adjust EAX to the range
    mov ecx, RangeOfNumbers             ; Range (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)
    xor edx, edx                        ; Needed for DIV
    div ecx                             ; EDX:EAX/ECX -> EAX remainder EDX
    mov eax, edx                        ; Get the remainder

    call write_number

    pop ecx                             ; Restore loop counter
    loop LL1

    invoke ExitProcess, 0               ; Returncode = 0

    err_exit:
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11            ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    push eax                            ; Place for WriteFile.NumberOfBytesWritten
    invoke WriteFile, eax, ADDR err_text, LENGTHOF err_text, esp, 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 1               ; Returncode = 1
main ENDP

write_number PROC STDCALL USES ebx                  ; printf ("%u ", EAX)
LOCAL numstring[20]:BYTE, NumberOfBytesWritten:DWORD
.CONST
    fmt db "%u ",0
.CODE
    invoke wsprintf, ADDR numstring, ADDR fmt, eax
    mov ebx, eax                        ; Preserve count of written bytes
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11            ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov edx, eax                        ; EAX will be used by the following INVOKE
    invoke WriteFile, edx, ADDR numstring, ebx, ADDR NumberOfBytesWritten, 0
    ret
write_number ENDP

END main
```

"Brand new" is the processor instruction `RDSEED` (at least [Broadwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadwell_(microarchitecture)) - since 2014). It meets the NIST SP 800-90B/C standard.

```
.686
.MODEL flat, STDCALL

INCLUDE kernel32.inc        ; GetStdHandle, WriteFile, ExitProcess
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib

INCLUDE user32.inc          ; wsprintf
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

NumberOfNumbers = 30        ; Number of random numbers to be generated and shown
RangeOfNumbers = 12         ; Range of the random numbers (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)

.CONST
    err_text db "ERR: RDSEED not supported.",10,0

.CODE
main PROC
    mov eax, 07h                        ; Check for availability (EAX=7, ECX=0) -> EBX.18
    xor ecx, ecx
    cpuid
    bt ebx, 18                          ; CPUID (EAX=07H, ECX=0H):EBX.RDSEED[bit 18] = 1 ?
    jnc err_exit                        ; No (RDSEED not supported) -> err_exit

    mov ecx, NumberOfNumbers            ; Loop counter - generate and show ECX random numbers
    LL1:
    push ecx                            ; Preserve loop counter

    @@:
    db 0Fh, 0C7h, 0F8h                  ; rdseed eax
    jnc @B                              ; Invalid number - try again

    ; Adjust EAX to the range
    mov ecx, RangeOfNumbers             ; Range (0..RangeOfNumbers-1)
    xor edx, edx                        ; Needed for DIV
    div ecx                             ; EDX:EAX/ECX -> EAX remainder EDX
    mov eax, edx                        ; Get the remainder

    call write_number

    pop ecx                             ; Restore loop counter
    loop LL1

    invoke ExitProcess, 0               ; Returncode = 0

    err_exit:
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11            ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    push eax                            ; Place for WriteFile.NumberOfBytesWritten
    invoke WriteFile, eax, ADDR err_text, LENGTHOF err_text, esp, 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 1               ; Returncode = 1
main ENDP

write_number PROC STDCALL USES ebx      ; printf ("%u ", EAX)
LOCAL numstring[20]:BYTE, NumberOfBytesWritten:DWORD
.CONST
    fmt db "%u ",0
.CODE
    invoke wsprintf, ADDR numstring, ADDR fmt, eax
    mov ebx, eax                        ; Preserve count of written bytes
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11            ; Get STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov edx, eax                        ; EAX will be used by the following INVOKE
    invoke WriteFile, edx, ADDR numstring, ebx, ADDR NumberOfBytesWritten, 0
    ret
write_number ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a [Pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), like in this answer:

[Pseudorandom generator in Assembly Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90184/pseudorandom-generator-in-assembly-language)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get random number in Assembly there are two ways I guess:

- If you are allowed to call a C function in Assembly you can use
  [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/).
- We used [NASM](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/) at the university and there is a command
  ([rdtsc](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Other_Instructions#Misc_Instructions)) in NASM that reads the CPU clock and place it in the
  registers. You can divide this number and get a random number.

I don't know about the MASM but Paul Carter's [NASM tutorial](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/) is great.