# Generating random 32bit number in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm looking for an assembly function that generate random number from 1 to n. n value could be about 60000. I have no idea how to do that. I've searched for this and i couldn't find any that met my excpectations.

Comment: For what CPU?  ARM, Motorola, Intel all have very different assembly instructions.

Comment: What platform/assembler?

Comment: @ Erick J. Intel
@Alex K. MASM x86

Comment: the same way you would in any other language...what problem are you having?

Comment: Are you looking for `RDRAND`?

Comment: @Cory Nelson i've tried to use it but i have this error: _Error 2 error A2085: instruction or register not accepted in current CPU mode_

Comment: @kobasek RdRand wikipedia page says: RdRand is an instruction for returning random numbers from an Intel on-chip hardware random number generator.RdRand is available in Ivy Bridge processors (
In some Ivy Bridge versions, due to a bug, the RdRand instruction causes an Illegal Instruction exception). so it better to use Linear Congruent Generator.

Comment: I've change .586 to .686 and it started to work. I mean it began to compile. Now when i'm trying to use it i got this: _An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in GUI.exe_

Comment: please add your code. see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for documentation about your error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomizing Numbers in Assembly with MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16170871), but that doesn't ask about limiting the range to 1..n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear Congruent Generator:

```
r[n+1] = (a * r[n] + c) % m
```

m = 65537 (2<sup>16</sup>+1)

a = 65538 (`a - 1` must be multiple of any prime divisor of `m`, and single divisor is `m` itself, i.e. 65537)

c = any even number (`c` and `m` must be relatively prime)

[Knuth, II vol., 3.2.1.1--3.2.1.2]

Comment: I want to use this algorythm in Miller–Rabin primality test. But, im passing to this test a variable which is another generated number. This variable is my higher range(0 - variable-1) How can i adjust this algorythm to this?

Comment: You can implement any LCG with large module, and then take the remainder when dividing by the `range`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator, where you'll find common used values of `a`, `c`, and `m`. You can use `m` that equal to power of 2 to simplify your code (and use higher bits of result, if you need more random generator). After all just `div` a random number by your range, and get remainder from `dx`/`edx` register.

Comment: Thanks, it works but after every compiling i get the same sequence of generated numbers. It's normal?

Comment: The sequence depends on initial value (r[0]). The exact initial value allows you to debug a program, cause the sequence is the same always. But in release version you should initiate the sequence by pseudo-random number, f.e. by result of the [`RDTSC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter).