# Reading a random line from a file in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to read from a text file containing 500 words in masm assembly x86, the task is to randomly pick 8 words from there. Can somebody please tell me how to do this?

This is the code to read from the file and displaying it on the console.

```
;READING FROM THE FILE
      invoke CreateFileA,offset filepath,1,0,0,3,128,0
      invoke ReadFile,eax, offset buffer,lengthof buffer, offset x,0

;DISPLAYING CONTENT OF BUFFER ON CONSOLE
      invoke GetstdHandle,-11
      invoke WriteConsoleA,eax, offset buffer, lengthof buffer, offset x,0
```

Here are some words from that file:

```
1.  abacus
2.  abacuses
3.  abaft
4.  abalone
5.  abalones
6.  abandon
7.  abandoned
8.  abandonedly
9.  abandonee
10. abandoner
11. abandoners
12. abandoning
13. abandonment
14. abandonments
15. abandons
16. abase
17. abased
18. abasedly
19. abasement
20. abaser
21. abasers
22. abases
23. abash
24. abashed
25. abashedly
26. abashes
27. abashing
28. abashment
29. abashments
30. abasing
31. abatable
32. abate
33. abated
34. abatement
35. abatements
36. abater
37. abaters
38. abates
39. abating
40. abatis
41. abatises
42. abator
43. abattoir
44. abattoirs
45. abbacies
46. abbacy
47. abbatial
48. abbe
49. abbes
50. abbess
```

Comment: Please don't show us pictures of text.  Instead, please add the content of the text file to the question.

Comment: Done that -_- now please tell me!!

Comment: Be patient! I have already begun writing an answer.  No need to be rude.  Instead, appreciate that somebody takes his time to help you.

Comment: I was not being rude. And i apology if you feel so!!

Comment: I listed some randomizing algorithms here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43392709/3512216. Maybe it helps ;-)

Comment: @rkhb please give a little more hint, i am so badly stuck with it! how can i randomly read 8 words out of 500 from a file?

Comment: @AnmolWajid What part of the algorithm in my answer is difficult for you to implement?  I can help you with the details as long as you tell me what part you can't do.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to get an arbitrary line from a text file.  Each line can have a different length and Windows does not keep track of where lines begin.

The general approach to this sort of problem is to read the entire file, picking lines at random along the way.  Commonly, the [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) method is used for this purpose.  It is quite easy to implement and carefully avoids any possible sampling bias.

Here is pseudo code for the relevant [algorithm R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Algorithm_R) as you might want to implement it:

```
Algorithm to pick k lines at random from file f:
    Let A be an array holding j lines.
    Read the first k lines from f and store them in A.
    Until f is empty:
        Read a line from f and let i be the number of lines you read so far.
        Pick a random number j between 1 and i inclusive.
        If j <= k then assign the line you just read to A[j].
    Return the lines in A.
```

Comment: How can i pick a random line in assembly?

Comment: @AnmolWajid You implement the reservoir sampling algorithm [Algorithm R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Algorithm_R) listed in the page I linked you to.  Implementing this algorithm is your job, I can only help you by pointing out what method to use.